# Placing the caret (cursor) in a specific position in a contenteditable field — problems during click

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

Here’s a strange problem I am facing.

I have a `contenteditable` field and implemented autocomplete functionality for hashtags for it. When a user starts typing a hashtag, they will see a popup box with autocomplete suggestions, like this:

[image]

The user can insert a suggested hashtag either using keyboard (selecting it with up/down arrows and pressing on Enter) or by clicking on it. The hashtag will be inserted, and the cursor placed in the end of the hashtag with the following function:

```
/*
 * The function takes a DOM node and the desired caret position
*/
var setCaretPosition = function(node, position) {
    node.focus();
    var textNode = node.firstChild;
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(textNode, position);
    range.setEnd(textNode, position);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
};
```

Now, here’s my problem. The above function works fine if the user selects the hashtag through keyboard (using arrows and pressing on Enter). But if the user clicks on a hashtag, the hashtag is inserted but the focus is lost from the text edit field.

I stepped through the debugger and verified that the DOM element I am trying to focus on and set the cursor in is the same element in both scenarios. But clicking on a hashtag will nonetheless lose the focus on the edit field. I have absolutely no clue as to why this may be happening. Perhaps you could offer any suggestions?

**Update:** Hmm, I must have made some mistake in my code, because this [simple example](http://codepen.io/azangru/pen/PZJgXB) I made in Codepen works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading my code for the umpteenth time, I realized that I was calling `stopPropagation`, but not `preventDefault` for the mousedown event on the hashtag when I was clicking on it. So it's not surprising that the focus was lost from my text field. I still find it somewhat puzzling that it was not restored with the code snippet I included in my question, but maybe that’s because I was listening to the `mousedown` event on the hashtag, and the focus, even if it was restored to the text field for a fraction of time, got lost again.